# How to add description to a Doctrine_Record class

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a table CustBillingEmployee described in the scheme below

```
CustBillingEmployee:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: cust_billing_employee
  columns:
    employee_num:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    job_title_code:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    cost:
      type: 'decimal(5, 2)'
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0.00'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    HsHrEmployee:
      local: employee_num
      foreign: emp_number
      type: one
```

and the class below

```
class cust_billing_employee extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->hasColumn('employee_num', 'integer',4,array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
        $this->hasColumn('job_title_code', 'integer',4,array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
        $this->hasColumn('cost', 'decimal',5,array(
            'fixed' => false,
            'unsigned' => false,
            'primary' => false,
            'default' => '0.00',
            'notnull' => true,
            'autoincrement' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->hasOne('User', array(
            'local' => 'employee_num',
            'foreign' => 'emp_number'
        ));
    }

    public function __toString() {
       return "HI";
    }
}
```

When I try to extract a particular object like so:

```
echo Doctrine::getTable('CustBillingEmployee')->find(1);
```

I get an error

```
No description for object of class "CustBillingEmployee"
```

I was hoping that the function __toString() gets overridden from the parent class but that is not the case. How shall I add a description to the object then?

When displaying each record I want to be able to display employee name instead of just employee_num key and job title instead of job_title_cost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post whole call stack, what code throws that error?

What is suspicious to me is the name of the class `cust_billing_employee` not being `CustBillingEmployee` and not extending `BaseCustBillingEmployee` which would be default behaviour of Symfony 1.4. Did you wrote this code 'by hand' ?

Since your schema is defined in schema.yml you should be using `./symfony doctrine:build-model` task.

This should generate correct classes: `CustBillingEmployee` extending `BaseCustBillingEmployee` which extends `sfDoctrineRecord` and then `Doctrine_Core::getTable('CustBillingEmployee')->find(1)` should work perfectly.

Also note, that you should not touch `BaseCustBillingEmployee` as this is meant to be autogenerated code, all modifications (like `__toString`) should be done in `CustBillingEmployee` class.